# How to make objects look like they’re coming towards you when I place them in stationary postions? Or have ball land on moving platform?

Tags: javascript, oop, animation, p5.js

I'm trying to create a ball hop game where the ball has to jump from one platform to another. However, I'm struggling with having the ball land on the platform and I think it might be because the platform itself is moving rather than the camera/background. Does anyone know a way I could move the camera, or a solution to the ball landing on the platform even if the platform is moving?

This is my code now.

```js
let gravity = 1.5;
class Ball{
  constructor(){
    this.x = 0;
    this.y= 200;
    this.d = 30;
    // constant velocity of the ball
    this.v = 0.001;
    this.xg = 0;
    this.yg = 0;
  }
  
  draw() {
    // stroke(0, 255, 255);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.d);
  }
  
  update() {
    this.draw();
    this.y += this.yg;
    // ensures that ball doesnt go past screen
    if (this.y + this.d + this.yg <= windowHeight) {
      this.yg += gravity;
    }
  }
}
class Platform{
  constructor({x,y}){
    this.x = x;
    this.y= y;
    this.w = 30;
    this.h = 30;
    this.s = 1;
  }
  
  draw(){
    push();
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rotateX(1.45);
    rect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
    pop();
  
  }
  
  move(){
    this.y = this.y + this.s
    this.s = this.s + 0.0001
  }
}

let ball;
let plat;
let scrollOffset = 0;
function setup(){
  createCanvas(710, 400, WEBGL);
  
  ball = new Ball();
  
  plat = [
    (new Platform({x:0,y:200})),
    (new Platform({x:50,y:100})),
    (new Platform({x:0,y:0})),
    (new Platform({x:-50,y:-100})),
    (new Platform({x:0,y:-200})),
     ];
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  
  ball.update();
  plat.forEach((plat) => {
    plat.draw();
    plat.move();
  });
  
 
  plat.forEach((plat) => {
      if (
        ball.y + ball.d <= plat.y &&
        ball.y + ball.d + ball.yg >= plat.y &&
        ball.x + ball.d >= plat.x &&
        ball.x <= plat.x + plat.w
      ) {
        ball.yg = 0;
      }
    });
   
  
  
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    ball.yg -= 20;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```